# I can't watch the flash video (e.g. youtube) with a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, firefox, flash

I'm running Precise Pangolin in my desktop pc; it works globally, but I can't watch any kind of flash video on the web.

I've installed flashplugin-installer and ubuntu-restricted-extras, like suggests in the answers, but nothing changes.

Maybe the problem is my Nvidia GeForce3 ???

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to install flash in firefox is to install the restricted extras packages. This can be done by typing in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Answer (score 1):

Flash plugin has not yet installed on your new install. Please use

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

or install the same from synaptic.

Comment: Please note that it's advisable to run `sudo apt-get update` before installing or updating software from the command-line. `sudo apt-get update` fetches updated information about what packages are available in what versions from where.